# DataError at /freshleadaction value too long for type character varying(20)

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am working on a django web app.
everything is working fine on my local machine and then pushed the code live on Heroku. but it doesn't work on the live server.
it gives the following error when I try to post a .csv file:

```
DataError at /freshleadaction
value too long for type character varying(20)
```

I have PostgreSQL database integrated. I deleted the migrations and then migrated the whole schema again. I think the problem is either PostgreSQL or heroku?
I have two models which are as follows:

```
class fresh_leads_model(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    legal_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sq_ft = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    orign_ln_amt = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prop_value = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    equity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    deleted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class cash_buyer_model(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    deleted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my views.py function:

```
def upload_fresh_leads(request):
    get_type = request.GET['type']
    lst = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        leads = Fresh_leads_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)

        data = request.FILES.getlist('csv')
        # data = Fresh_leads_Form(request.FILES)
        # csv_file = request.GET['csv']
        # df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        # return HttpResponse(print(df)))

        # data = []

        # message = 2
        # return render(request, 'admin/src/tabs/fresh_leads.html', {'message': message})
        if get_type == '1':
            
            if leads.is_valid():
                # csv = data['csv']
                for d in data:
                    print('dataaaa :::::::::::', d)
                    # df = pd.read_csv(d, usecols=['Owner First Name'])
                    # return HttpResponse(df.to_string())

                    df = pd.read_csv(
                        d,
                        # print('dataaaa :::::::::::', d),
                        dtype='str',
                        
                        names=[
                            'Owner First Name',
                            'Owner Last Name',
                            'StreetNumber',
                            'StreetName',
                            'State',
                            'Zip Code',
                            'Bdrms',
                            'Legal Description',
                            'Sq Ftg',
                            'Address',
                            'Orig Ln Amt',
                            'Prop Value',
                            'Equity',
                            'Email',
                            'Cell'
                        ])
                        
                    # print('data frame', df)
                    df = df.fillna(0)
                    df.columns = [
                        'Owner_FirstName',
                        'Owner_LastName',
                        'StreetNumber',
                        'StreetName',
                        'State',
                        'ZipCode',
                        'Bdrms',
                        'Legal_Description',
                        'Sq_Ftg',
                        'Address',
                        'Orig_Ln_Amt',
                        'Prop_Value',
                        'Equity',
                        'Email',
                        'Cell']

                    json_record = df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')

                    lst = json.loads(json_record)

                    bulk_data = df.to_dict('records')

                    model_instances = [fresh_leads_model(
                        fname=i['Owner_FirstName'],
                        lname=i['Owner_LastName'],
                        street_number=i['StreetNumber'],
                        street_name=i['StreetName'],
                        state=i['State'],
                        zip_code=i['ZipCode'],
                        bedrooms=i['Bdrms'],
                        legal_description=i['Legal_Description'],
                        sq_ft=i['Sq_Ftg'],
                        address=i['Address'],
                        orign_ln_amt=i['Orig_Ln_Amt'],
                        prop_value=i['Prop_Value'],
                        equity=i['Equity'],
                        email=i['Email'],
                        cell=i['Cell']
                    )for i in bulk_data]
                    fresh_leads_model.objects.bulk_create(model_instances)

                # message = 2
                # return render(request, 'admin/src/tabs/fresh_leads.html', {'data': lst, 'message': message})
                return redirect('main:FreshLeadView')
        # message = 1
        # return render(request, 'admin/src/tabs/fresh_leads.html', {'message': message})

        # message = 3
        # return render(request, 'admin/src/tabs/fresh_leads.html', {'message': message})

    return render(request, 'frontend-layout/500.html')
```

full error trace back:

```
DataError at /freshleadaction
value too long for type character varying(20)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://www.realtorbit.com/freshleadaction?type=1
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: DataError
Exception Value:    
value too long for type character varying(20)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Comment: You have a model field with max_length=20 somewhere, and you're trying to store more than 20 characters in it...

Comment: yes, I know but now I changed it from 20 to 255. but still facing this error. I deleted the migrations and database and made migrations again.but still facing this error on live server. my code works fine locally when I upload a .csv file. but not on live server

Comment: I'm guessing you're using sqlite in dev (which doesn't enforce such limits) and PostgreSQL in prod (which does enforce such limits). There could be more than one field..?  The full traceback should give you more information about which field it is.

Comment: @thebjorn I think this is the thing that is making it confusing to me. I am totally confused. but in settings.py file, I have integrated PostgreSQL databse.

Comment: In both dev and prod? Same version of the database?

Comment: when i do migrations, it makes schema in sqlite3 but not in postgresql. what should I do now?

Comment: I don't know about the versions of the databases at the moment.

Comment: @thebjorn should we discuss it in a private chat?

Comment: I don't know anything about Heroku, but there seems to be documentation about how to migrate prod: https://help.heroku.com/GDQ74SU2/django-migrations

Comment: okay, let me check it. i will be back

Comment: @thebjorn Hi. I am still facing the same error. because migrations didn't make any changes. I followed all the steps.

Comment: Hopefully someone with more Heroku knowledge will be able to help you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for your efforts. Actually, I applied all those solutions before posting my problem here but suddenly I got an idea and I removed all my `Charfields` from my **fresh_leads_model** and **cash_buyer_model** and left their parameters empty(I mean without `max_length=255`). although `CharField` was working on my local machine but was not working on a **live server**. so I decided to change it from `CharField` to `TextField` without `max_length` limit so **Heroku** supported it and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I don't see any limits on Heroku about using CharField. So your solution (marked as "Accepted") is in using TextFields? Really? 

Comment: Yeah, I was also confused but when I replaced CharField with TextField then everything worked correctly. so I marked it as accepted for TextField so that if someone faces any error related to CharField and TextField using Heroku, then he/she can look into my answer. if you have any comments, let me know please

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you "deleted the migrations and then migrated the whole schema again," but clearly something must be left over from your original schema.

I would suggest:

1. Delete the entire database in Heroku if you don't care about the data: `heroku pg:reset DATABASE`.
2. Push up your latest code to Heroku (including the new migrations in a new `git commit`): `git push heroku HEAD:main`.
3. Migrate the database: `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Hi Malan. Thanks, I did many times before your answer but nothing changed. I solved just by removing Charfield to Text Field and removing max_length restriction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no model with `max_length=20` in the sources codes that you've provided. So you need to search for it in other models.
Pay attention:

1. In Python you need to use CamelCase in class names, so make edits like

```py
class cash_buyer_model(models.Model):
```

->

```py
class CashBuyerModel(models.Model):
```

2. Because this is a Model so you no need to use it in the class names:

```
class CashBuyer(models.Model):
```

3. I see that you've mentioned that you've already found the needed field, you need to [push updated code on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Comment: hey, @fanni thanks for your response but the problem was not about the model names. I solved the issue by myself and let me explain in a new answer.